# how to include env variables into Webpack 5?

Tags: javascript, webpack, environment-variables

I know there is a lot of documentation online, and several questions related with this, but nothing seems to work.

I have a simple vanilla JS project, bundled with webpack.

This is my `webpack.dev.js` file:

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  mode: 'development',
  devtool: 'eval-source-map',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve('public'),
    filename: 'dist/bundle.js',
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          'style-loader',
          'css-loader',
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.svg$/,
        use: 'file-loader',
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.EnvironmentPlugin(['CUSTOM_PATH']),
  ],
  devServer: {
    static: './public',
  },
};
```

This is my `.env` file:

```
CUSTOM_PATH=https://test.s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/test/dev/
```

And finally this is the script on my `package.json`

```
"start": "export $(xargs < ../.env) && webpack serve --open --config webpack.dev.js",
```

When I start the project, I got an error, saying `process` is not defined, when trying to do a simple `console.log(process.env.CUSTOM_PATH)`

> `Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: process is not defined`

This will run on the browser, not in a node server.

What's missing? How can I build with an environment variable?

Comment: @jabaa ok yes, but when webpack builds it, it should replace, right? I mean, react or angular, both runs on the browser, but they can handle process.env on their code before bundle

Comment: I thought `new webpack.EnvironmentPlugin` would do that, if you know how to do that, I would appreciate a link :)

Comment: Now I get `Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: CUSTOM_PATH is not defined`

Comment: DefinePlugin and EnvironmentPlugin won't parse your .env file, I suspect, if you will pass environment variable directly, it'll work `"start": "CUSTOM_PATH=https://test.s3.. export $(xargs..`

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov I tried that also, but then webpack returns an error:

`CUSTOM_PATH environment variable is undefined`

Answer (score 3):

Ended up updating my `webpack.dev.js` to

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  mode: 'development',
  devtool: 'eval-source-map',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve('public'),
    filename: 'dist/bundle.js',
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          'style-loader',
          'css-loader',
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.svg$/,
        use: 'file-loader',
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': {
        CUSTOM_PATH: JSON.stringify(process.env.CUSTOM_PATH)
      }
    }),
  ],
  devServer: {
    static: './public',
  },
};
```

Without the `JSON.stringify` does not work for some reason, even if it's already a string.

Comment: DefinePlugin worked for me. Only way I found so far that does!